# Building ML Model in AWS Sagemaker autopilot with Time Series feature

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio, autopilot

I am building a classification model in AWS Sagemaker using Autopilot. I have imported a dataset which has a time series feature. This features includes a list of values in each cell. The data set is structured as follows:

| Target | time_series_feature |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [12,12,5,6,7] |
| 1 | [34,23,5,6,7] |

I believe Autopilot can take time series features while building a model. However, when I import the data in Atopilot the time_series column shows up as "Text" and there is no option to tag it as a time series input.

How do I get Autopilot to recognise this as a time series input?